# getDeviceList() always empty

Tags: android, arduino, usb, device

I'm trying to use an Arduino Board along with my Odys Neo x8 tablet but it seems, that the UsbManager doesn't recognize the device alright. I connected the arduino to the tablet via an OTG-adapter so that the tablet will work in host mode, the Arduino is successfully receiving power from the device.
I'm fetching the list of available USB-devices on the tablet as follows:

```
sUsbController = new UsbController(this, mConnectionHandler, 0, 0);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devlist = sUsbController.mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
        TextView t = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView));
        t.setText("Found " + Integer.toString(devlist.size()) + " devices");
```

And inside the class UsbController:

```
mUsbManager = (UsbManager) mApplicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

But unfortunately, the list remains empty, even if i start filtering using the VID and the PID (the two zeros).
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following code which works very fine with keyboard, mouse and Mass Storage device to connect with Pandaboard,

```
  UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
  HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devicelist = usbManager.getDeviceList();
  Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = devicelist.values().iterator();

  while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
    UsbDevice usbDevice = deviceIterator.next();
    Log.i(Log_Tag, "Model     : " +usbDevice.getDeviceName());
    Log.i(Log_Tag, "Id        : " +usbDevice.getDeviceId());
  }
```

This should work with Arduino too.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino board [needs a driver](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Howto) which needs to be installed before it can be accessed.

I am not sure if you have a port of the driver for Android.

**Edit**:

Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9683684/24949) in another thread.

Comment: I followed [link](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549) on implementing it, so yes, it got a driver somehow. Here's the complete one: http://pastebin.com/hANbdq3U

Comment: no :( i checked with a programm called "USB device info" from the market, there nothing is listed under accessible for android (tried USB stick, keyboard and Arduino) but under "Linux" (so accessed via the file-system) they are visible...