# Android UsbManager DeviceList is Empty

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I want to establish serial communication between Android and Arduino. My Android device supports OTG. When I run this code, I get empty result. (I've tried SanDisk USB, Arduino, USB Bluetooth).

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText("Hello");
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
while(deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
  UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
  tv.setText(device.getDeviceName());
```

AndroidManifest;

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="12"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
```

Where is my error? (Sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006889/usbmanager-getdevicelist-returns-empty) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299393/getdevicelist-always-empty) links

Comment: I have tried before this. Nothing Changed :) @HBizhi

Comment: Perhaps your phone doesn't actually support OTG, or your adapter cable isn't grounding the id pin.   Does plugging in a usb mouse or keyboard work?

Comment: Your code is broken though, as you keep writing the results in the same text view so only the last will show.  You probably want to append them or use some sort of list view.

Comment: Yes, I've tried plugging usb mouse and keyboard. There are working :) @ChrisStratton

Comment: If result are be not empty, textView text will be changed. @ChrisStratton

Comment: The only value you are likely to see will be the last one.  While probably not your primary problem, it's not hard to imagine cases where that could appear empty even when other entries are not.