# Can Java application use USB Host on Android 2.2 device?

Tags: java, android, usb, archos

I have Archos 101 Internet tablet which has USB host mode, but it's Android version is only 2.2.1 . As I read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/index.html , Android has USB API from version 3.1 as well as in 2.3.4 . Is is there any way Java application to communicate through USB on such device with 2.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started in the right direction:

[using serial port RS-232 in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621580/using-serial-port-rs-232-in-android)

It's likely you will need to get your hands on the kernel source which I believe Archos usually publishes shortly after a device hits the market. Grab the current config.gz off your device and figure out what kernel modules you may need and recompile. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response! The device on the other side is with usb too, I dont think serial cable is suitable. Also, for now I dont want to hack the tablet (kernel), its out of my current area of expertise. If there is no any other Java API which can be used, probably a new tablet with newer Android will be better decision.

Comment: From what I can recall it's built in on Android 3.x, however that never stopped anyone from hacking it in. I'd almost wait and get an ICS tablet, or buy a XOOM which is pegged for the update from Motorola.