# Building kernel module for Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I need to add the FTDI USB module to the Android kernel (Android 2.3.1, Linux 2.6.32), so I got the 2.6.32 kernel and tried to build the module:

```
make modules ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-
```

But when I tried to do 'insmod ftdi_sio.ko', the error message was

```
insmod: init_module 'ftdi_sio.ko' failed (Exec format error)
```

In dmesg's output I found this

```
ftdi_sio: version magic '2.6.32.27 preempt mod_unload ARMv5 ' should be '2.6.32.27 preempt mod_unload ARMv7 '
```

I tried to add 'armv7-a' flag (as I read in Android NDK docs)

```
make modules ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi- CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp'
```

Also, I tried following cross-compilers: arm-none-eabi-, arm-eabi-, arm-linux-android-eabi-

Every time result was the same - ARMv5 in the version magic.
How can I build the module for ARMv7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting up `CONFIG_CPU_V7=y` in your kernel `.config` file