# How can we enable events for RS232 communication in Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it possible to single an event to user space application when some data traffic is detected on serial communication (RS 232) ? basically I don't want my Android to clog where a thread keeps waiting for data from serial port rather this could be streamlined to fire an event to user application to check for data from serial port once data is detected.

Kindly let me know if is possible if not what alternate methods can be employed to handle this situation in Android/Linux device drivers.

Comment: What about this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621580/using-serial-port-rs-232-in-android

Comment: Thanks, but this more to USB-serial , USB by itself gives support for Udev events which can throw up events to user land. Is it possible to fire events to android app just with RS 232 driver?